# Delete table with cascade does not delete rows in referenced table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, in PostgreSQL 15.2:

```
CREATE TABLE first
(
  id serial INT NOT NULL,
  A INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE second
(
  id serial INT NOT NULL,
  f_id INT NOT NULL,
  B INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id
    FOREIGN KEY (f_id)
      REFERENCES first(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I populated them quite simply:

```
INSERT INTO first VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO second VALUES (1,1);
```

I did a `DROP TABLE first CASCADE;` and I expected to get an empty `second` table, but the data is still there with a `f_id` even when `first` is empty.

Did I misunderstand how `DROP ... CASCADE` works or did I forget to declare something at creation time? I thought `DROP` is like a `DELETE` at a row level and `CASCADE` removes any foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between Data Definition Language (setting up and modifying the schema) and Data Modification Language (inserting, updating, and deleting data).

`CREATE TABLE`, `DROP TABLE` and `CONSTRAINT` belong the the DDL. If you drop the table, it removes the table (including its data) from the schema. This fails if the table is still referenced by other entities in the schema (like the foreign key constraint on the other table). If you drop the table with `CASCADE`, it also removes those other entities recursively. So you removed only the `fk_id` constraint, you did not modify the data of the `second` table.

> I thought `DROP` is like a `DELETE` at a row level and `CASCADE` removes any foreign key constraint.

No. `DELETE` is the row-level DML statement for removing data from a table. Use `DELETE FROM first;`, it will delete all the values (but keep the table definition itself), and it will cascade to the referencing data in the `second` table.

You might have been looking for [`TRUNCATE first`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) as well, possibly `TRUNCATE first CASCADE` which is the same as `TRUNCATE first, second;`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes! Thanks for clarifying and reminding me of the TRUNCATE function. Very much appreciated!